error while following mvc pattern in nodejs
index.js
const express = require("express")
const cors = require('cors')
const morgan = require('morgan')
const colors= require('colors')
const dotenv = require('dotenv')


const app = express()

dotenv.config()
//middleware
app.use(cors());
app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(express.json())
app.use("/api/v1/test",require('./routes/testroutes'))

const port = process.env.PORT



app.get("/",(req,res)=>{
    return res.send("I am here for you");
})

app.listen(port,()=>{
    console.log(`server is running on ${port}`.bgCyan.yellow)
})

testcontroller.js
const testcontroller=(req,res)=>{

    try{
        res.send("<h1>I am iron man</h1>")
    }
    catch(error){
        console.log("some thing is found",error)
    }
   
};

module.exports = {testcontroller}

routes
const express = require("express");
const { testcontroller } = require("../controller/testcontroller");


const router = express.Router()

router.get('/some',(req , res)=>{
    return res.send('test user',testcontroller);
})

module.exports=router;



when I try to visit /api/v1/test/some I am getting following error
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The first argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, ArrayBuffer, or Array or an Array-like Object. Received function testcontroller
at Function.from (node:buffer:324:9)
at ServerResponse.send (O:\backend\food\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:194:22)
at O:\backend\food\routes\testroutes.js:8:16
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (O:\backend\food\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at next (O:\backend\food\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:149:13)
at Route.dispatch (O:\backend\food\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:119:3)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (O:\backend\food\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at O:\backend\food\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:15
at Function.process_params (O:\backend\food\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:346:12)
at next (O:\backend\food\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:280:10)
^V
I want to know why I am having this error.

The problem is in routes file you are trying to send a response that is actually a function therefore the error occurs. I am guessing you want /some to point to testcontroller so here is how to do that.
router.get('/some', testcontroller)

